# How to use a variable search range in index match or equivalent?

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

My data is structured as seen here.
[image: Data Structure]

I have an Index Match function to retrieve the data from 2017

**=INDEX(D:D,MATCH("x",$A$3:$A$5,0)+2,1)**

which works.

Now, I would like to retrieve the data from 2016 or 2015, depending on what the user selects in another cell and hence have the D:D range change automatically to C:C or B:B. I will need to replicate that for each indicator A, B, ...

How could I achieve this? I tried to play with Offset or Index Match Match but with no luck.

Thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDEX(B:D, MATCH(B7,$A$3:$A$5,0)+2, MATCH(B8, $B$2:$D$2))
```

Then if you enter `x` into B7 and `2016` into B8 you'll get a return of `2`.

You'll need to adjust exact cell references as needed.

Comment: Just beat me to it ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, it works flawlessly :-)